# jQuery using on in place of live gives the wrong "this" in the callback

Tags: jquery, live

I've been trying to debug this for a while and I'm not sure where things are going wrong or what possibly may be affecting it. The code is kind of too big to try to replicate but I will try the best I can to explain what I am encountering (I also didn't want to use live because it has been deprecated).

```
$(document).on('click', someSelector, function(evt) {
     evt.preventDefault();

     // Do something

     console.log(this);
});
```

In the console.log, I am getting #document back and I am not sure why. I am wondering if it could possibly be conflicting with some other code that I have though I can't really show the rest of the code because its too big to be copied and pasted here so I guess regarding to this issue, what may be causing such a behavior? Personally, I thought it was kind of weird but could anyone tell me what may be happening that causes this behavior and why jQuery might be handling the ways its handled here? Any help would be gladly appreciated. Thanks!!!

Comment: What is `someSelector`? Can you post the rest of your code or a full example on http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: hey blender, here is the jsfiddle that may be of interest though i'm not sure if it tells too much about the problem! http://jsfiddle.net/QFzzZ/ thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You specified your event handler on `$(document)`. That makes `this` your `document`. You want to be looking at `evt.target` instead if you are interested in which element triggered the event.

Comment: i have that somewhere else and it worked perfectly fine and was able to target "someSelector" though; if i did not mistaken i think it was a recommended way of implementing live with on, please correct me if i'm wrong though

Comment: is this not a good way to do it?  
http://api.jquery.com/live/  
`$(document).on(events, selector, data, handler); // jQuery 1.7+  `

Comment: It is the good way to do it. I'm just saying that what you need lives in `evt.target`, not in `this`. `this` will be the element where the handler is defined, not the element that receives the event. It's like telling your friend Charlie to tell you his name whenever he sees someone passing on the street, then getting annoyed when he starts saying "Charlie, Charlie, Charlie..." Everything else is as it should be, you're just using the wrong variable.

Comment: thanks! so by practice i should always reference the `evt.target` rather than `this`?  
i also think i might have found the reason why it may have been doing that.. it appears that it could not find the `self.$elem` which in the simple example is `someSelector`. sorry guys; i guess i just overlooked it.. thanks though for the help :)